# Where is the folder with ReSharper snippets?

Tags: resharper

In Visual Studio there is a folder where snippets are stored:
`c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC#\Snippets\1049\`

Where is the folder where the `ReSharper` snippets are stored?

**Pic-1.**
[image]

**Pic-2.**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper stores templates in its settings files. The settings file can be stored in a number of places, including per-project, per-solution, and machine-wide settings. The "Layer" dropdown on your second screenshot allows you to see/edit templates from a particular settings source. You can read more about ReSharper settings and where they are stored in [Manage and share ReSharper settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html).